# calculate average work hours of a month query but different logic for current month?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an Employee_Attendance table which has the following fields :

Date, Shift, IN, OUT, Late In, Early Out, Holiday, Workhour

with sample data as

```
Date           IN       OUT     Late_In    Early_Out    Holiday    Workhour
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
01-04-2017     09:04    17:58     00:04        :            :       08:54
02-04-2017     08:41    17:25       :        00:05          :       08:44
```

I have used the following query to find the average of workhours based on the number of working days in a month

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(cast(SUM(DateDiff(MINUTE,  CAST('0:00' as time), WORKHOUR))/60 as nvarchar(3)) + ':' + cast(SUM(DateDiff(MINUTE,  CAST('0:00' as time), WORKHOUR))%60 as nvarchar(2)),'-') AS TOTALWRKHRS,                                                                                                                                                                                        
    ISNULL(RIGHT('0' + cast((SUM(DateDiff(MINUTE,  CAST('0:00' as time), WORKHOUR))/"+workingdays+")/60 as nvarchar(3)), 2)  + ':' + RIGHT('0' + cast((SUM(DateDiff(MINUTE, CAST('0:00' as time), WORKHOUR))/"+workingdays+")%60 as nvarchar(2)) , 2),'-') AS AVGWRKHRSWRKHRS

FROM 
    "+currMonthVal+" m,"+currYearVal+" e 
WHERE 
    E.EMPID=M.EMPID AND 
    E.LOCATION=M.LOCATION AND M.EMPID = ?
    and (DATENAME(WEEKDAY, attdate) not IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') or
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ATTDATE,3) in ("+resultantWL+") ) and
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ATTDATE,3) not in ("+resultantHL+")
```

where

- **workingdays** is the number of working days in a month which I have calculated in another query
- **currMonthVal** is the current month abbreviation (e.g JAN, FEB, March..) passed from outside
- **currYearVal** is the current year value (e.g 2011,2012..) passed from outside
- **resultantWL** is the extra working days (e.g 13-04-2017) passed from outside [This value is actually a date fetched from a table-'ExtraWorkingDays' in another query]
- **resultantHL** is the holiday dates (e.g 05-04-2017,14-04-2017) passed form outside [This value is actually a date or array of dates fetched from a table-'Admin_Holiday' in another query]

*Now*
this query works fine but it finds the average of the workhours based on the number of working days in a month and what I want is if the month is the current month then the average should be according to the number of the days till date, for e.g if the month is May-2017 with 22 working days and today is 05-05-2017 then it should calculate the average of workhours by taking the value 5 and not 22 and on later date by taking the value 6 and not 22. This data/table is showed on a GUI as a dynamic table.

Kindly let me know what changes need to be made in this query.

Moreover, I have only SELECT priviledge on the Employee_Attendance table

Comment: Your query is not valid SQL, could you please at least provide the working script you are using, along with the expected output for the new logic?

Comment: Added a edit suggestion for easier readability.

Comment: Judging from the SQL you are using (Find and Replace values on table names?  Different tables for different months of the same data?) you have some significant design issues going on here.  What you are doing is very straightforward in a normal SQL table structure.  In your monstrosity?  Good luck...

Comment: These are the actual values or the table names in database.                
String currMonthVal =  "IPR"+currentYear1+".DBO."+currentMonth1;
String currYearVal  =  "IPR"+currentYear1+".DBO.emp"                                     Just need a query so as to find the average of workhours based on the number of days of month till date if it is current month. Any way other then the query that I have used would also be appreciated.

Comment: No it not much clear.Suppose I hv to find working hour for year 2017 and month March.Then what is my input.and wht i write in from clause.Also wht parameter you are passing in proc.month and year ?

Comment: wht is the meaning of this where attndate not in Saturday and sunday then again you find value in Extraworking days.In fact you hv to thorw table structure ,their relation and sample data of all 3 tables.including extra working days example.

Comment: This means that I do not to consider the saturdays and sundays and resultantWL is actually  extra working day if any exists in a month. While calculating the sum and average I need to make sure that it doesn't count any weekends but count any extra working day because the extra day falls on either saturday or sunday

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1 : If it is current month and year then find avg working hours till date else for whole month

Soltion :

```
declare @month varchar(20)='JAN'
declare @year int=2017

declare @FromDate date=cast(@year as varchar)+'-'+@month+'-'+ '01'
declare @ToDate date

if(datepart(month,@FromDate)=datepart(month,getdate()) 
and datepart(year,@FromDate)=datepart(year,getdate()))
set @ToDate=getdate() -- till date
else
set @ToDate=DATEADD(day,-1, dateadd(month, datediff(month,0,@FromDate)+1,0))--last day month

select @ToDate
```

Now Simply find records between these date.It will solve one of your problem.

Do you maintain table for each month and year ?In that case your DB design is wrong .

But first get your query correct using hard coded month and year then you can convert it into dynamic SQL

Comment: Yes for each year and not each month. I do  not have Database access except for SELECT priviledge. Could you please help in a way so that the above task can be performed in a single select query. I can not use anything other than Select statement